# Is there a way to scrape the text inside a tag which has no attributes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

the html code looks like this

```
<td> Single cylinder, Liquid-cooled, DOHC, BOSCH EFI </td>
```

I could just use this code :

```
soup.find_all('td')
```

but, i want the tags with no attributes separately.
So, how can I extract the tags specifying they do not have any attributes ?

Comment: Well, you could filter all the elements in `soup.find_all('td')` such that they have no attributes!

Comment: @DaveIdito how can it be done ?

Comment: yeah it did @Sushanth. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `soup.find_all()` and check manually through `attrs` attribute

You can do this:

`tags = soup.find_all("td")`

`tags = [i for i in tags if not i.attrs]`

And then get the **text** from the new tags list

`tags_text = [i.text for i in tags]`

`attrs` is an attribute to get the list of all attributes of an element